# Phabricator - Source code appears in .hg folder

Tags: mercurial, phabricator

For initiating my project, first, I push my code to Phabricator repository by using `hg` instead of `arc`.

Then I accepted commits on Phabricator.

But I suspect that I had done wrong somethings. Because the source code appears in `/var/repo/M/.hg/store/data/` path.

I'm wondering that is everything normal?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/repo/` is the configurable root, `M/` the name of your repository in phabricator. I think the rest is the default structure of a mercurial repository. It always creates a similar folder structure within `.hg/store/data/` than the workspace itself looks like.
So, yes, everything is normal as phabricator hosts a mercurial repository.

More precisely, files ending in `.i` in the `.hg` directory are index files in [revlog format](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Revlog). Sometimes you will also see `.d` files next to the `.i` files (short for data), but with the newest revlog format, the index files can also often hold the data as well, allowing `.d` files to be omitted. The rest of the filename is based on the name of the original file, with certain characters (such as symbols and upper case) encoded differently; for example, the `~2e` prefix in the screenshot represents a dot character (`.`, ASCII code 0x2e).

Comment: I had thought that in my pc - which I code on it - .hg folder is located in main project folder together my source code unlike the repo of Phabricator. Thanks.